# Excel-like JTable Cell Editor, with an empty cell at edition start

Tags: java, jtable

I'm trying to have a JTable edition working like in excel: if I start editing a cell, the cell becomes empty for receiving the new entry. The goal is to avoid the user having to delete the existing cell content first.

I can already detect cell start/stop edition by adding a PropertyChangeListener working as follow:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
{
    //  A cell has started/stopped editing
    if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
    {
        if (table.isEditing())
            processEditingStarted();
        else
            processEditingStopped();
    }
}
```

Trying to clear the table model at processEditingStarted() does not work with the code bellow:

```
private void processEditingStarted()
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( this );
}

public void run()
{
    row = table.convertRowIndexToModel( table.getEditingRow() );
    column = table.convertColumnIndexToModel( table.getEditingColumn() );
    oldValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
    newValue = null;

    table.getModel().setValueAt(null, row, column);
    table.updateUI();
}
```

However the editor content keeps the former value.

Does someone has clues to hide the current value of the cell during edition?

Optionnaly it should be able to restore the former cell content if the user did not actually modify the value.

Comment: Never invoke updateUI() for something like this. Read the API to find out the proper usage of this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I"ve never seen a spreadsheet remove data when you start editing a cell.

[Table Select All Editor](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/table-select-all-editor/) shows a different approach.

Comment: Excel and OpenOffice both hide the existing data when you start editing. Your suggestion is great: it does not hide content as expected, but at least, since the content get selected, direct edition replace previous content. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. First I am using the event **keyReleased** and then getting the row and column number on which I am working and then setting the value at that row. Code goes like this.

```
private void purchases_TBLKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {      
    int rowWorking = purchases_TBL.getSelectedRow();
    int columnWorking = purchases_TBL.getSelectedColumn();

    if(columnWorking==3){
        model.setValueAt(null, rowWorking, columnWorking);
    }
}
```

This makes the third column of the table null as soon as I focus move on to that using keyboard.

**Note**: The same piece of code can be placed in **MouseClicked** event.